# Angular Event handler firing for every instance of component

Tags: angular, events, event-handling, components

I have a page (hostview) in which I dynamically create components that holds information including a p-tree that the user creates in the UI.  I add them with a button from the hostview, and I delete them with a button on the tree component, which passes the event back to the host view via a notificationService like so:

Creation in the hostview:

```
constructor(@Inject(Loader) service, @Inject(ViewContainerRef) viewContainerRef, public dataCenter: DataCenterService,private router: Router) {
    this.service = service;
    this.trees = this.dataCenter.getTreeState();
    this.service.setRootViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef)
    this.newTree();
}



newTree() {
    var newTree = this.service.addDynamicComponent();
    newTree.instance.ref = newTree;

    newTree.instance.service.onDestroyEvent.subscribe(
      treeRef => {
        for(var i=0;i<this.trees.length; i++){
          if(this.trees[i].instance.ref == treeRef){
            this.trees.splice(i,1);
          }
        }
       }
      );
    this.trees.push(newTree);
}
```

Notification service:

```
export class NotificationService {
    onDestroyEvent: EventEmitter<ComponentRef<ConnectionTreeComponent>> = new EventEmitter();
    constructor() {}
}
```

tree component:

service:NotificationService;

```
constructor(public dataCenter: DataCenterService, public treeService: TreeDragDropService, service:NotificationService) {
   this.service = service; 
}

ngOnDestroy() {
   this.service.onDestroyEvent.emit(this.ref); /*ComponentRef passed back to hostview*/
}
```

So this does technically work, but it is called once for every instance of the the tree component instead of just the once.  How can I fix this to work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the NotificationService and put the onDestroyEvent into the tree component, and refactored accordingly.  That solved the repeat event problem.